# How to give customers an option to change their currency?

Tags: magento2

I want the customers to have an option where they can switch between different currencies by selecting from a drop-down menu, and have that change take effect store-wide. The default currency will be USD when a customer signs up but they should have an option of changing it themselves.

Comment: follow this [link](https://belvg.com/blog/managing-multiple-currencies-in-magento-2.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that you need to setup Multiple currencies via admin backend.

please check this link, it might be helpful to you:

[Configure Multiple Currency.](https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/how-to-configure-currency-magento-2.html)

Answer (score 0):

you need to setup Multiple currency via Admin Side,

Steps-> Go to admin dashboard and go to store and go to configration and chosse the General,and go to currency  setup and change the currency  and set the multiple currency  in your site,